# How can I access and work on the same branch of a remote repo from two different machines?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-branch, git-remote

At work we have a remote repo which for the purpose of this question I will call `work-repo`. I have a windows machine which I do all of my work on, and on this machine I have a branch, which I will call `work-repo/windows-branch`. I have pushed changes, but these changes have not been merged with `origin/master`.

This branch involves making sure the project works well on both windows and mac machines. I have a mac VM running on my machine which is set up to access the remote `work-repo`. What I would like to do is have access to `work-repo/windows-branch` and be able to work on and do testing on both machines.

The trouble is I cannot see this branch from the mac machine. I have tried `git branch -r` which shows several branches, but not the one I'm looking for, `git branch --no-merged master` which shows now branches, `git branch -r --no-merged master` which shows a branch, but not the one I'm looking for, and `git branch -r --no-merged origin/master` which shows the same branch as the previous command.

If I go onto our bitbucket page I can see the branch there. What is it that I'm missing and what would be the process by which I can access `work-repo/windows-branch` from the mac and work on it from both machines simultaneously? Once I have access to `work-repo/windows-branch` will I need to do commits on one machine before having access to the changes on the other? The project must be working for both machines before it can be merged with origin so I'm not sure if this is a problem or not.

Its possible this is a simple problem, but I'm fairly new to git and was unable to find a solution by researching this specific need online. If this is the case, I apologize and I appreciate any help offered.

Update: I realized I hadn't done a `git fetch` and I can now see the branch in `origin`. Any input on the best way to work on this branch simultaneously on the two separate machines would still be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You work on the branch on two machines by committing/pushing/pulling, same as for any other branch.

Comment: Yes, I figured that was the process for making changes between machines. But what is the proper way to get that same branch on my second machine? I've tried doing a `git fetch` followed by `git checkout origin/windows-branch` but I get an error: "The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout...please move or remove them before you switch branches". I'm not sure why I need to remove files if I'm creating a new branch and it makes me think I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: `git checkout windows-branch`. It will create a new local branch tracking the remote branch.

Comment: @DanielMann When I do this I get the above warning I mentioned as well.

Comment: You have uncommitted changes in whatever branch you currently have checked out. You can't switch branches with uncommitted changes. If you don't care about those changes, then you can discard them. If you do care about them, commit them.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I should have known it was this simple. Please answer and I'll select it as the solution.